# Symfony and Doctrine - cannot remove item from collection (Many-to-Many relation with extra field)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

Good day everyone!
I have a question about collection persistence in Symfony and Doctrine

**The short version**

I can add an item to collection (persist) via form, but can not remove (remove).

**The logics**

I need a possibility to add users to business trips. Each added user must have text description (like a objective for business trip).

In fact, i have 3 entities:

- BusinessTrip
- BusinessTripUser (stores linked User id, BusinessTrip id and text field "description")
- User (vendor bundle entity)

**The problem**

As i already said above - i cant remove BusinessTripUser from collection $users in BusinessTrip.
I mentioned that if i remove unidirectional relation between BusinessTripUser and User - everything work fine. It looks like this relation prevents orphanRemoval mechanism delete the orphaned BusinessTripUser enity.

**Relations between entities**

[image]

```
class BusinessTrip
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OQ\BusinessTripBundle\Entity\BusinessTripUser", mappedBy="businessTrip", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $users;
}
```

```
class BusinessTripUser
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OQ\BusinessTripBundle\Entity\BusinessTrip", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="business_trip_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $businessTrip;
}
```

Symfony v2.7.3, Doctrine v2.5.1

Comment: The documentation is a bit confusing but basically, orphan removal is not going to work as expected for many to many relations.  That is because BusinessTripUser has a relation to BusinessTrip as well as User.  You need to call $em->remove($businessTypeUser);

Comment: @Cerad, yes, this solution will work, but i think that there must be another way, a bit easier. In theory, we define all these persistence options in entity classes to delegate all the dirty routine tasks to Doctrine. Otherwise we can do everything in controller (get attached and detached entities and set relations manually), but this is not Symfony way, imo